# How to write a file in specific path in ruby

Tags: ruby, file, dir

I want to save my files in specific path.. 
I have used like this

```
file_name = gets 
F = open.(Dir.pwd, /data/folder /#{@file_name },w+)
```

I'm not sure whether the above line is correct or not! Where Dir.pwd tell the directory path followed by my folder path and the file name given.

It should get store the value on the specific path with the specific file name given. Can anyone tell me how to do that.

Comment: Don't give me down vote.. If ppl know d mistake means help it. Without knowing or understanding or knowing the answer how can u down vote?  leave ppl to post their questions to find answers

Comment: Please execute the code, and see if it works, if it does not, give a precise error message or explain why the observed behaviour is wrong

Comment: `File.write("#{Dir.pwd}/#{gets}", 'How this is working?')`. I'll let you figure it out how this is working. Probably you should look at [File class](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html) and its parent [IO class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html). After that consider it homework and change it to serve your purposes. Regards

Comment: Don't beg people to not give down votes. Instead, make sure you've asked a well thought-out question. You *could* have tested your code in IRB to figure out whether it was valid, or simply run it and Ruby will tell you when you try to run it. Those are the very first things you should do, and when you've read the documentation and exhausted your resources, THEN show what you've tried and say why it didn't work and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: @the Tin Man I'm not begging here..thanks for your info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has multiple errors. Have you ever tried to execute the script?

Your script ends with:

```
test.rb:7: unknown regexp options - fldr
test.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
    F = open.(Dir.pwd, /data/folder /#{@file_name },w+)
```

First: You need to define the strings with `'` or `"`:

```
file_name = gets 
F = open.(Dir.pwd, "/data/folder/#{@file_name}","w+")
```

Some other errors:

- You use `file_name` and later `@file_name`.
- The `open` method belongs to `File` and needs two parameters.
- The file is defined as a constant `F`. I would use a variable.
- The path must be concatenated. I'd use `File.join` for it.
- You don't close the file.

After all these changes you get:

```
file_name = gets
f = File.open(File.join(Dir.pwd, "/data/folder/#{file_name}"),"w+")
##
f.close
```

and the error:

```
  test.rb:29:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Temp/data/folder/sdssd (Errno::ENOENT)
```

The folder must exist, so you must create it first.

Now the script looks like:

```
require 'fileutils'
dirname = "data/folder"
file_name = gets.strip
FileUtils.mkdir_p(dirname) unless Dir.exists?(dirname)
f = File.open(File.join(Dir.pwd, dirname, file_name),"w+")
##fill the content
f.close
```

Comment: Rather than assign `open` to a variable then later `close` it, use the block form of `open`.